# Filtering RecyclerView with 4 different Spinner

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I am currently trying to implement a search function for `RecyclerView` containing custom items in form of `CardViews` with 4 different `TextViews`. 
I want to use 4 different spinner elements, each covering one `textView`.

For now I tried the search with one spinner only, but it does not work.

Custom RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class WorkersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Worker> workers, filtered;
private Context c;
private int lastPosition = -1;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView levelracein, nodein, cityin;
    public ImageView iv;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        levelracein = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.levelracein);
        cityin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityin);
        nodein = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nodein);
    }
}


public WorkersAdapter(Context c, List<Worker> workers) {
    this.c = c;
    this.workers = workers;
    this.filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    this.filtered.addAll(this.workers);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.worker_list_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int pos = position;
        Worker worker = filtered.get(position);
        holder.levelracein.setText(worker.getLevel() + " " + worker.getRace());
        holder.cityin.setText(worker.getCity());
        holder.nodein.setText(worker.getNode());

    setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return workers != null? workers.size() : 0;
}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
{
    if (position > lastPosition)
    {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}

public void filter(final String level, final String race, final String city, final String node) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            filtered.clear();
            if (level.equals("None")) {
                filtered.addAll(workers);

            } else {
                for (Worker worker : workers) {
                    if (worker.getLevel().toLowerCase().contains(level.toLowerCase())) {
                        filtered.add(worker);
                    }
                }
            }

                ((Activity) c).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Notify the List that the DataSet has changed...
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();

}


}
```

The Spinner listener:

```
levelspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            onQueryTextChange(levelspinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    racespinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    cityspinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    nodespinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

The function to feed the search in RecyclerView:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String level, String race, String city, String node) {
    wa.filter(level, race, city, node); //wa -> WorkersAdapter
    return true;
}
```

The question is,

1. How to implement a search which will add all the different spinner selections and search more precise with every spinner item selected?
2. Why does my RecyclerView still display cardViews which are empty after selecting?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more details , why you want to use spinner @ProgFroz

Comment: I have 4 different textviews inside the cardview and the user should be able to filter on each textview, for example if he rather wants to filter for the level, he uses the spinner for level, if one of the three others, then he uses these. If he also wants to filter for 3 different things, he can use these.

Comment: Can you explain in more brief, i'm not getting you , Do you want to change the position of that 4 textview which is inside recycler_row/cardView or something else ? @Prog

Comment: If you have design image, please attach with your question

Comment: Added, there you can see that each spinner is refered to one textview. Each textview has a different variety of choices and therefore I cannot use one simple SearchView.

Comment: Now tell me , Is your spinner ABCD have some items , when you select one of them , like if you select one item in spinner A it will filter and show you the result on reyclerview ??

Comment: It should show me all CardViews which contain a TextView with that selection of the spinner

Comment: Can you replace all these spinner with one edittext , when you search on edittext it will show you result by comparing all four textviews of all rows.

Comment: I would not like to actually. There are 2 spinners which display a string array of 3-5 Strings, the other two are more than 20.

Comment: i have answered your question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getItemCount()` to below code on Adapter class , you used here two ArralList reference when you search it will showing result by your `filtered`  ArrayList  reference . so you have to return `filtered.size()`

```
   @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filtered!= null? filtered.size() : 0;
}
```

As per your Comment you want search all of these spinners in single filter change with below code

```
for (Worker worker : workers) {
                if (worker.getLevel().toLowerCase().contains(level.toLowerCase())  ||  2nd searchitem      ||   3rd searchitem     ||  4th searchitem  ) {
                    filtered.add(worker);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! But how can I put all of these in a row and filter for example for 3 different spinner selections at once?

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help you , Happy Coding

Comment: Actually I noticed a problem, now even if one spinner is wrong, due to to the || operator, the cardview will still be visible if he contains at least one true item of the 4 spinners.